# C++ Creating a class and an enum class creates error

Tags: c++, class, enums

So I have 4 files called Token.h , Token.cpp  Lexer.cpp and Lexer.h... In Token.h I have in it an enum class which contains certain Tokens needed for my application.

I am trying to create a class in Token (which is NOT the enum) as I need to return the Token and the string (which I pass from Lexer.cpp)

The problem is this. When I try to create this class in Token.cpp

#### token.cpp

---

```
class Token
{ // Code needed
};
```

and I declare it in Token.h (in which contains all this code)

#### Token.h

---

```
enum class Token
{ 
// Tokens needed for app 
......
......
}


class TokenLookup
{
public:

    Token tk;
    std::string str;

private:

    Token getToken();
    std::string getString();

    void setToken(Token sToken);
    void setString(std::string strbuffer);

};
```

---

#### Token.cpp Method that needs to return a TOKEN

```
Token Lexer::getNextToken()
{
    char ch;
    string bf ="";
    ch = ReadChar();

    while (input)
    {
        input.get(ch);

        if (isWhitespace(ch))
        {
            cout << "WS" << endl;
        }
        else if (isdigit(ch))
        {
            while(isdigit(ch))
            {
                bf += ch;
                cout << bf << endl;
                ch = ReadChar();
            }
            if(ch != '.')
               {
                    // DO nothing for now
               }
        }
        else if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            cout << " letter " << endl;
        }
        else if (isPunctuation(ch))
        {
            cout << " Punctuation " << endl;
        }
        else if (isArithmeticOperator(ch))
        {
            cout << " Arithmetic " << endl;
        }
        else if (isComparisonOperator(ch))
        {
            cout << " Comparison " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"error" << endl;
        }

        }

     //cout << "Row " << Row << " Col " << Col << " Offset " << Offset << endl;

        return Token (tokenNeeded, string) //WARNING! I'VE JUST INVENTED THESE PARAMETERS AS E.G

}
```

in Lexer.h (in which I have the Token.h header file included in it) it pops up an error stating

```
||=== Build: Release in Compilers (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
E:\University\Compilers\Compilers\lexer.h|27|error: multiple types in one declaration|
E:\University\Compilers\Compilers\lexer.h|27|error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I am guessing since i have 2 different classes in token.h.. but the error pops up in LEXER.h not in Token.h, What does it mean it's not declaring anything? Prior to do this class (class TokenLookup) It was working perfectly

Any way I can fix this? Or do I need a new file?

The whole concept is that in Lexer.cpp I begin checking each character what it is.... and then I Return that Token + its string (to be added to a Vector) so at the end, I can continue checkign the next

Thanks

Comment: What's this `}; TokenLookup` supposed to do?

Comment: Why is Token a class in one file and an enum class in the other? And what's up with the extra "TokenLookup" at the end?

Comment: I saw it on a tutorial somewhere, should name the class or so it said. To be honest I didn't actually understand it. I've tried removing it, and it brings out a new error, that I am redefining the class and there is already a definition of TokenLookup

Comment: You also need `;` after class definition

Comment: I have that, but the error is that I have redefinition of classes (since now I have 2 in Token.h),

Comment: In token.cpp you have to also declare it as `enum class` and not just `class`

Comment: Not related to the problem you're having, but if those `get` and `set` methods are trivial (i.e. they don't do anything else but set or get the variable), they can be removed to reduce the amount of code.

Comment: I mainly have a method (found in Lexer.cpp - will upload it's code), which has to return a TOKEN value (found in token.h), so any idea if I can structure that code will be grateful

Comment: Name your `enum class Token` something that is not the same name as `class Token`

Comment: still the same, I'll see whether I can change something